# How can I force a large matrix to be horizontally centered and allow it to exceed both margins?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, margins, matrices, marginpar

I am trying to get a very large matrix to be centered. I know that it is too large to fit within the margins, but I still want it with its current size. As shown in the figure below, the matrix overlaps only with the right margin and I would like it to be horizontally centered and exceed both margins symmetrically (e.g., if it exceeded the right margin by 1 cm then it also should exceed the left margin by 1 cm).

If possible, I would like the solution to have `array` environment in it or at least and another environment that allows me to draw horizontal and vertical lines inside the matrices as shown below:

[image]

My source code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand {\arraystretchdefaultl} {1.3}
\newcommand{\arraystretchdefault}{ \renewcommand {\arraystretch} {\arraystretchdefaultl} }
\arraystretchdefault

\usepackage[showframe = true]{geometry}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
    \left[
        \begin{array}{c}
        V_{i} \\ \midrule[0.25mm]
        0
        \end{array}
    \right]
    %
    =
    %
    \left[
        \begin{array}{c c!{\vrule width 0.25mm} c c}
        & Z_{orig} &  & col. \medspace k - col. \medspace p \\ \Xcline{1-4}{0.25mm}
        & row. \medspace k - row. \medspace p & & Z_{th,kp}+Z_{b}\\
        \end{array}
    \right]
    %
    \left[
        \begin{array}{c}
        I_{i} \\ \midrule[0.25mm]
        I_{q}
        \end{array}
    \right]
\end{equation}


\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth, center}

    \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
    %
        \begin{equation}
        %
                %
                \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
                \left[
                    \begin{array}{c}
                        V_{1} \\
                        \vdots \\
                        V_{l} \\
                        \vdots \\
                        V_{k} \\
                        \vdots \\
                        V_{p} \\
                        \vdots \\
                        \vdots \\ \midrule[0.25mm]
                        0 \\
                    \end{array}
                \right]
                =
                \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
                \left[
                    \begin{array}{c c c c c c c c c !{\vrule width 0.25mm}c}
                        & & & & & Z_{1k} & \dotsm & Z_{1p} & \dotsm & Z_{1k} - Z_{1p} \\
                        & & \scalebox{1}{$Z_{orig}$} &  & & \vdots & & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
                        & & & & & Z_{lk} & \dotsm & Z_{lp} & \dotsm & Z_{lk} - Z_{lp} \\
                        & & &  & & \vdots & & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
                        Z_{k1} & \dotsm & \dotsm & Z_{km} & \dotsm & Z_{kk} & \dotsm & Z_{kp} & \dotsm & Z_{kk} - Z_{kp} \\
                        \vdots & & & \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
                        Z_{p1} & \dotsm & \dotsm & Z_{pm} & \dotsm & Z_{pk} & \dotsm & Z_{pp} & \dotsm & Z_{pk} - Z_{pp} \\
                        \vdots & & & \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
                        \vdots & & & \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots &  & \vdots \\ \Xcline{1-10}{0.25mm}
                        Z_{k1} - Z_{p1} & \dotsm & \dotsm & Z_{km} - Z_{pm} & \dotsm & Z_{kk} - Z_{pk} & \dotsm & Z_{kp} - Z_{pp} & \dotsm & Z_{th, kp} + Z_{b} \\
                    \end{array}
                    \right]
                    \left[
                    \begin{array}{c}
                        V_{1} \\
                        \vdots \\
                        V_{l} \\
                        \vdots \\
                        V_{k} \\
                        \vdots \\
                        V_{p} \\
                        \vdots \\
                        \vdots \\ \midrule[0.25mm]
                        0 \\
                    \end{array}
                    \right]
                %
                \arraystretchdefault
        %
        \end{equation}
    %
    \end{minipage}

\end{adjustbox}




\end{document}
```

Comment: Centered relative to the text area or relative to the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this?

[image]

for spilling out on both side of text width i use macro `adjustwidth` from package `changepage`. i rewrote your matrix (make it shorter for one column) and use smaller font for it too.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\newcommand {\arraystretchdefaultl} {1.3}
\newcommand{\arraystretchdefault}{ \renewcommand {\arraystretch} {\arraystretchdefaultl} }
\arraystretchdefault

\usepackage[showframe = true]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
    V_{i} \\ \midrule[0.25mm]
    0
\end{array}\right]
    %
    =
    %
\left[\begin{array}{c c!{\vrule width 0.25mm} c c}
    & Z_{orig} &  & col. \medspace k - col. \medspace p \\ \Xcline{1-4}{0.25mm}
    & row. \medspace k - row. \medspace p & & Z_{th,kp}+Z_{b}\\
\end{array}\right]
    %
\left[\begin{array}{c}
    I_{i} \\ \midrule[0.25mm]
    I_{q}
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}

\begin{adjustwidth}{-3em}{-5em}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
    \small
\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
    V_{1}   \\
    \vdots  \\
    V_{l}   \\
    \vdots  \\
    V_{k}   \\
    \vdots  \\
    V_{p}   \\
    \vdots  \\ \Xcline{1-1}{0.25mm}
        0   \\
\end{array}\right]
    =
\left[\begin{array}{cc cc cc cc !{\vrule width 0.25mm} c}
        &        &        &        & Z_{1k} & \dotsm & Z_{1p} & \dotsm & Z_{1k} - Z_{1p}    \\
        &        &        &        & \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots             \\
        &        &  Z_{orig}       
                          &        & Z_{lk} & \dotsm & Z_{lp} & \dotsm & Z_{lk} - Z_{lp}    \\
        &        &        &        & \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots             \\
Z_{k1}  & \dotsm & Z_{km} & \dotsm & Z_{kk} & \dotsm & Z_{kp} & \dotsm & Z_{kk} - Z_{kp}    \\
\vdots  &        & \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots             \\
Z_{p1}  & \dotsm & Z_{pm} & \dotsm & Z_{pk} & \dotsm & Z_{pp} & \dotsm & Z_{pk} - Z_{pp}    \\
\vdots  &        & \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots             \\ \Xcline{1-9}{0.25mm}
Z_{k1} - Z_{p1}
        & \dotsm & Z_{km} - Z_{pm}
                          & \dotsm & Z_{kk} - Z_{pk}
                                            & \dotsm & Z_{kp} - Z_{pp}
                                                              & \dotsm & Z_{th, kp} + Z_{b}
\end{array}\right]
%
\left[\begin{array}{c}
    V_{1}   \\
    \vdots  \\
    V_{l}   \\
    \vdots  \\
    V_{k}   \\
    \vdots  \\
    V_{p}   \\
    \vdots  \\ \Xcline{1-1}{0.25mm}
        0   \\
\end{array}\right]
        \end{equation}
            \arraystretchdefault
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```